# Android onClick method

Tags: android, button, onclick

I have two onclick method in android project

```
    clr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    clr.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            tv1.setText("CLR");

            et1.setText("");
            refrigerant = "";
            pres = "";
            temperature = "";

            superheat_oda = 0;
            sub_cool = 0;
}
    });
```

And i have onther onClick method in which i have to call that method directly

```
    prs=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    prs.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                     -----      I have to call that method---

                                                 }
    });
```

Is there Any Solution for this?

Comment: I suggest you follow `benvd` suggestion, but still for the sake of it,
use `clr.performClick()` in the Listener.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to call the first `onClick` from the second? Just extract the contents of your first onClick in a separate method and call that method from each `onClick`.

Edit: As per st0le's comment, you can do what you want by calling `clr.performClick()`. (Didn't know that.) Still, extracting it into a separate method seems cleaner.

Answer (score 13):

you can do something like this in the XML file

> ```
> <Button
>  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>  android:onClick="some_function" />
> ```

and put this function in the Java file

```
public void some_function(View view) {
 // stuff...
}
```

and put the some_function in both "onClick"s

Comment: The `(View view)` function parameter is the gotcha. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You should turn to use the simplest way that I always do as below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

}

private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
             switch(v.getId()){
                 case R.id.button1:
                      //DO something
                 break;
                 case R.id.button2:
                      //DO something
                 break;
              }

    }
};
```

Comment: a button suggestion would be to break every case. that would make it allot more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use the same OnClickListener for both buttons if both buttons really have to do the same thing:

```
OnClickListener l=new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        tv1.setText("CLR");

        et1.setText("");
        refrigerant = "";
        pres = "";
        temperature = "";

        superheat_oda = 0;
        sub_cool = 0;
    }
};
clr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
clr.setOnClickListener(l);
prs=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
prs.setOnClickListener(l);
```

or if its not exactly the same you could access the listener method by l.onClick(null); manually..